# GCP FHIR viewer does not show data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, hl7-fhir, google-healthcare-api

I am trying to implement GCP FHIR store.

Like it says on the [GCP documnentation](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/fhir-search#searching_across_all_resource_types), I should be able to see data when I click the resource type.

However, I see 18 data exists at the pagination section at the the bottom, but data does not show.

I am able to click little empty space of a row and it shows overview but elements and json tab of the data is not available.

Since I cannot embed an image, I will share a [link of an image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RMCXFXVAJbW4B1HVkhIoy3LptffUgmnl/view?usp=sharing).

Thx in advance.

Comment: This appears to be a bug, you can report it by clicking the Help icon in the top right of the Cloud Console (question mark button), and then clicking on "Send Feedback"

Comment: This does sound like a bug. If you could post feedback using the "Send Feedback" tool like Nik has indicated, that would be a huge help. Please attach any Javascript console errors or any other information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thx everybody. I will post an answer if I get answers from google.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, this seems like a bug on GCP's side.
You can report it on the [Public Issues Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1138369) including symptoms and reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Console has identified a bug in FHIR viewer in which certain types of data would not render under certain circumstances pertaining to dates.

A fix has been submitted and should be included in an upcoming release, usually deployed within a week.